# Image(s) are missing width and/or height attributes in magento

Tags: php, image, ce-1.8.1.0, css, html

I analyzed my website on Gtmetrix.com for optimization and the result was this:

> The following image(s) are missing width and/or height attributes:

```
http://mywebsite.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/168x168/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/1/11.jpg
(Dimensions: 168 x 168)
http://mywebsite.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/168x168/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/1/11_1.jpg
(Dimensions: 168 x 168)
```

> **Specify image dimensions**
>
> allows for faster rendering by eliminating the need for unnecessary
>   reflows and repaints.Specifying a width and height for all images

how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your templates for `<img>` tags and where you find one that you are sure it has some fixed size, just add `width=".." height=".." on it`.

For sections where the product images are displayed (product list, view, related, upsells, crosssels, cart, wishlist) you should know the size because most of them have a resize.
In your case think there is something like `->resize(168)` or `->resize(168, 168)`.
this means you have to add this to your `img` tag: `width="168" height="168"`

Answer (score 2):

**Any img tag use like this. its works grt just check out.**

```
<img width="236" height="193" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image') ?>"  alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" />
```